# How to "push and shift" an element in a numpy array most efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to add a `numpy array` `x = [1,2,3,4]` to "the end" of a numpy array of shape `(n,4)` (i.e. "push" `x` onto the array) while removing the first element (i.e. "shift" the array). So basically, after adding my array `x`, the `(4)` shaped array that was added last should be removed.

How does one do this in the computationally most efficient manner?

Comment: Can you provide a small example?

Comment: The obvious approach of moving the n-1 rows to make room for the new one, involves a lot of copying - in effect making a new array with each addition.  But for some kinds of access you can get by without the move, just keep track of where you are putting the new data.  Another approach is to start with an array that's much larger than `n`.  In general though numpy arrays are not optimal for ring buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a ring buffer.  Just use a normal NumPy array plus an integer which tells you which row is the "top."  To push, simply replace the "top" row with a new row and increment the top index.